# Define operator[]() (array subscription) for template class outside of class definition

Tags: c++, templates

I thought this would be easy, but it's not working the way I expected.  What is the correct syntax here?

**TemplateClass.h**

```
template <typename T> 
class TemplateClass
{
  T & operator[](size_t n);
```

**TemplateClass.cpp**

```
#include "TemplateClass.h"

template <typename T>
T & TemplateClass::operator[](size_t n)
{
  // member declaration not found
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? With templates, you normally define the entire thing in the header and don't have a .cpp file at all.

Comment: Ah, because the linker needs to find the definition when it instantiates the template?  Good point.

Comment: @user2887734 Yes exactly!

Comment: This is an FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/templates-defn-vs-decl.html

Comment: @ChristianHackl There's also a popular post here on SO: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide the whole class name – including template arguments:

```
template <typename T>
T & TemplateClass<T>::operator[](size_t n)
{
  // ...
}
```

(Also note that the scope resolution operator is `::`, not `:`.)

Comment: ... and don't you put the implementation into a separate compilation unit!